# Twilio: loop message and wait human interaction before dialing

Tags: twilio

I am using Twilio to establish a phone call between two persons. 
I use Twilio C# API to call the first person from my number and to invoke a TwiML bin that says a welcome message and dials a call to the second person.

```
var from = myNumber;
var to = firstPeson;
var templateUrl = $"{config.template_url}?Dial={secondPerson}&Welcome={welcome}";
CallResource.Create(new PhoneNumber(to), new PhoneNumber(from), url: new Uri(templateUrl), client: restClient);
```

and the TwiML bin:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Say>{{Welcome}}</Say>    
  <Dial>{{Dial}}</Dial>
  <Hangup/>
</Response>
```

The problem is when the first "person" is a call center. It does not hear the TwiML bin welcome message. 
My guess is that the TwiML bin is executed when the call arrives in the call center dispatching queue, before a human picks up the phone.

So, my idea was to loop the welcome message and to use Gather to wait a human to interact before invoking another bin for the dialing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
 <Gather numDigits="1" finishOnKey="#" timeout="60" action="https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/123456789123456?Dial={{Dial}}">
    <Say loop="0">{{Welcome}}</Say>    
  </Gather>
</Response>
```

The problem here is

- the loop does not end when the key # is pressed. With loop="10", # does not interrupt the loop.
- we cannot pass the number to dial as a parameter for the action method because {{Dial}} in the url causes an error.

Is it possible to interrupt the loop when the key # is pressed?
How can I pass the Dial parameter between bins?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you set `numDigits="1"` on a `<Gather>` you can actually use any button to break the loop and trigger the action. I would recommend removing `finishOnKey="#"` and just let the user press any button.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Removing `finishOnKey="#"` works, I can break the loop and invoke an action url. Now, how can I pass the Dial parameter to this action url?
I have an error when I add it as a querystring :
`action="https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/123456789123456?Dial={{Dial}}"`

Comment: What's your error? It would likely be best if you accept this answer as correct for the question you asked and then asked a new one to deal with the new error.

Comment: A voice says that an error occured after pressing a button, ie when invoking the action. It gives no precision. This was part of my original question (How can I pass parameter between bins) but fine, I will create another one. Thank you.

Comment: In my case only pressing # key breaks the loop and other keys repeat the <say> inside <gather>